# Error in configuring hibernate 5.0.2

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem when I use hibernate 5.0.2, I try to find solution but failed. I don not know where the problem is.

this is hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
   <property name="connection.username">mecro</property>
   <property name="connection.password">mecro1234</property>
   <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver/property>
   <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName="Micarle";characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
   <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect.class</property>

   <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <property name="format_sql">true</property>
   <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

   <mapping resource="Students.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

this is test class

```
public class StudentsTest {
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private Session session;
private Transaction transaction;

@Before
public void init(){
    //Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();

    StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
    sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
}
@After
public void destroy(){
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
}

@Test
public void testSaeStudents() {
    Students s = new Students(1, "mecro", "man", new Date(), "montains");
    session.save(s);
}
```

this is the error when i run the class as junit test

```
 org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number -1 and column -1 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg", local:"property"). Expected elements are <{
```

there are some failure trace follow this error.but I can not copy it,  and I think they mean nothing

Comment: Please add the error you're getting to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the line you specify that SQLServerDriver property .... you missed a `<`